# Difference between kubcetl top node memory and pods memory

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster with single node where there is a large discrepancy between kubectl top node and aggregate pod usage? Where can I find the difference between both of them

```
kubectl top node
NAME                                CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
aks-agentpool-87273576-vmss000000   380m         9%     4923Mi          39%
```

```
 kubectl top pods --sum=true -A

..

 ________     ________

  152m         2023Mi
```

Where do I look for the additioanl (4923-2023)Mi on the node? I have tried using `top` and `free` command

I expect to get a better idea of the memory usage

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl top node` displays the actual usage of your Kubernetes Nodes.
It is a reserved resource to be used also by the Kubernetes components like kubelet, kube-proxy, etc.

When a pod is deployed, Pod resources will be taken from the [Node allocatable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable) resources for pods.

Comment: How can I tally the usage from kubectl top node with the usage of kubelete, kube-proxy etc